# unmarshal an xml file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

[UPDATE]
i am trying to use jaxb to store xml element into an arraylist.
i saw many tutorials for storing below xml format into an object or arraylist

```
<country>
   <name>nepal</name>
   <zip>123</zip>
</country>
```

and i tried with different kind of xml file like below and that did not work out

```
<TransactionList>
<Transaction type="D" amount="61" narration="Electricity bill" />
<Transaction type="D" amount="32" narration="Social security payment" />
<Transaction type="D" amount="33" narration="Payment sent to x" />
<Transaction type="C" amount="111" narration="Salary" />
<Transaction type="D" amount="233" narration="Car rental" />
```

i tried like this below code

```
try {

                File file = new File("C:\\Users\\anon\\Desktop\\Transaction_Data.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transaction.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                Transaction transaction = (Transaction) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(transaction);


              } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

my pojo class(Transaction.java)

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TransactionList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transaction {

@XmlElement(name="type")
private String type;

@XmlElement(name="amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@XmlElement(name="narration")
private String narration;

@XmlElement(name = "Transaction")
private List<Transaction> transaction= null;

public List<Transaction> getTransaction() {
    return transaction;
}

public void setTransaction(List<Transaction> transaction) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
}
```

i am getting this as output now

```
com.progressoft.induction.tp.models.Transaction@0
```

when i try to do this

```
transaction.getAmount();
```

then i get null

Comment: Try `@XmlAttribute` instead of `@XmlElement`

Comment: no luck, i am getting null output :(

Answer (score 0):

Code needs minor changes to accommodate list of Transaction against a single Country object.

Class containing List of transactions:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "transactions")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transactions
{
    @XmlElement(name = "transactions")
    private List<Transaction> transactions= null;

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions= transactions;
    }
}
```

Transaction class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transaction 
{
    private Integer type;
   .......
```

Business logic:

```
Transactions transactions = (Transactions) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(transaction);
```

Comment: hi thanks, i am getting com.progressoft.induction.tp.models.Transaction@0  as output now when i try transaction.getAmount() like this i get null output

Comment: @JasbinKarki need to add BigDecimal Adapter here.  Eg. @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BigDecimalAdaptor.class)
private BigDecimal amount;